# Youtube Player API: hide controls when video ended and show last frame

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have a HTML 5 youtube video player.

I want that when the video ends playing, hide control bar.

I already got the callback function for when the video has ended played. Do you know if there is a way to hide the control bar at the end? Or any similar idea for achieving this?

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        //hide control bar??
    }
};
```

Moreover, I want the player to show the last frame of the video instead of going back to the main picture of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found an alternative way to accomplish this.

You should add an interval checking for the current time of the video and if its near the end, just pause it :D

```
intv = setInterval(updatePlayerInfo, 250);

function updatePlayerInfo() {
    duration = player.getDuration();
    current = player.getCurrentTime();

    if (duration > 0 && (duration - 0.250) <= current && current <= (duration + 0.250)) {
        player.pauseVideo();
        clearInterval(intv);
    }

}
```